# In the Stepper widget, it draws the content starting from one click inside, how can I prevent this?

Tags: flutter, stepper

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/controller/signup_controller.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/pages/widgets/button_widget.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/pages/widgets/gender_widget.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/pages/widgets/text_button_widget.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/pages/widgets/text_form_field_widget.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/utils/global_colors.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/utils/global_strings.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SignupPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignupPage> createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  int currentStep = 0;
  Gender? selectedGender;

  final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController surnameController = TextEditingController();

  continueStep() {
    if (currentStep < 2)
      setState(() {
        currentStep = currentStep + 1;
      });
  }

  canselStep() {
    if (currentStep > 0)
      setState(() {
        currentStep = currentStep - 1;
      });
  }

  tappedStep(int value) {
    setState(() {
      currentStep = value;
    });
  }

  Widget controlsBuilder(context, details) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        currentStep <= 1
            ? ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
                child: Text("İleri"),
              )
            : Container(),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        currentStep > 0
            ? OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
                child: Text("Geri"),
              )
            : Container()
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: GlobalColors.white.withOpacity(0.95),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Stepper(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            type: StepperType.horizontal,
            elevation: 0,
            currentStep: currentStep,
            onStepContinue: continueStep,
            onStepCancel: canselStep,
            onStepTapped: tappedStep,
            controlsBuilder: controlsBuilder,
            steps: [
              Step(
                title: const Text('Adım 1'),
                isActive: currentStep >= 0,
                state:
                    currentStep >= 1 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
                content: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    TextFormFieldWidget(
                      controller: nameController,
                      hintText: 'İsim',
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      obscure: false,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    TextFormFieldWidget(
                      controller: surnameController,
                      hintText: 'Soyisim',
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      obscure: false,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        GenderWidget(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedGender = Gender.male;
                            });
                          },
                          text: 'Erkek',
                          icon: Icons.male,
                          boxColor: selectedGender == Gender.male
                              ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          iconColor: selectedGender == Gender.male
                              ? Colors.blue
                              : Colors.grey,
                          textColor: selectedGender == Gender.male
                              ? Colors.blue
                              : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        GenderWidget(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedGender = Gender.female;
                            });
                          },
                          text: 'Kadın',
                          icon: Icons.female,
                          boxColor: selectedGender == Gender.female
                              ? Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.5)
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          iconColor: selectedGender == Gender.female
                              ? Colors.pink
                              : Colors.grey,
                          textColor: selectedGender == Gender.female
                              ? Colors.pink
                              : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        GenderWidget(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedGender = Gender.notSpecified;
                            });
                          },
                          text: 'Belirtilmemiş',
                          boxColor: selectedGender == Gender.notSpecified
                              ? Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          textColor: selectedGender == Gender.notSpecified
                              ? Colors.black
                              : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Step(
                title: Text('Adım 2'),
                isActive: currentStep >= 1,
                state:
                    currentStep >= 2 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
                content: Column(),
              ),
              Step(
                title: Text('Adım 3'),
                isActive: currentStep >= 2,
                state:
                    currentStep >= 3 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
                content: Column(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
text_form_field_widget.dart
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:social_uni_official/utils/global_colors.dart';

class TextFormFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TextFormFieldWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.controller,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.keyboardType,
      required this.obscure,
      required this.icon});
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final bool obscure;
  final IconData icon;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 55,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        color: GlobalColors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: GlobalColors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            blurRadius: 10,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        obscureText: obscure,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          border: InputBorder.none,
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            icon,
            color: GlobalColors.darkNavyBlue,
          ),
        ),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          color: GlobalColors.darkNavyBlue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GenderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const GenderWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.text,
      this.icon,
      required this.boxColor,
      this.iconColor,
      required this.textColor});
  final Function() onTap;
  final String text;
  final IconData? icon;
  final Color boxColor;
  final Color? iconColor;
  final Color textColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: boxColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            icon != null
                ? Icon(
                    icon,
                    color: iconColor,
                  )
                : Container(),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: textColor,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the stepper widget, it draws the content starting from one click inside, how can I prevent this? As seen in the picture and code, the only padding I give is the padding of the largest wrapper container, but it still makes the content in the stepper widget steps smaller as if it has a little more padding. How can I fix this? The places I indicated in red color in the photo.

I can't remove it, even though I give padding to content nowhere, it still stays inside like a red line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWwnO.png) This is picture!